# Metatrader 5 datafeeder

Tags: server, metatrader4, metatrader5

I try to write my own datafeeder for Metatrader 5 using Gateway API. I compiled Gateway API examples, but when I try to run them, my Metatrader test server says: "datafeeder status - offline". It just couldn't see my datafeeder. Does anybody have any ideas or samples how to connect datafeeders to server?

Comment: Could you post a links to that you want to compile ?

Comment: You can check sample code of SampleExchange provided with GatewayAPI doc as an example. If you run SampleExchange and SampleGateway you can see SampleGateway status is Online. Follow the changes done in these codes to change status Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I just had to move datafeed.exe to Metatrader Server Datafeed folder.